# qsort error with big sample

Tags: c, qsort

I am using `qsort` for an `int` array in the `struct`.

```
struct venue {
    int Pos;
    int *number;
};

int cmpfunc(const void * a, const void * b) {
        return ( *(int*) a - *(int*) b);
}
```

I allocate an `int` array memory by this way below:

```
 newvenue.number = (int*)malloc(1000000 * sizeof (int));
```

and run the `qsort` function by,

```
qsort(venueArray[i].number, (venueArray[i].Pos + 1), sizeof (int), cmpfunc);
```

`venueArray[i].Pos` count the total elements in the `venueArray.number`. I am wonder should I change the `cmpfunc` as I am sorting `int` array in the `struct` rather than `int` array

This code is working fine when I use small sample but will fail using big sample like 100 000 value in each `venueArray.number`

> [1]    32132 segmentation fault

Comment: Why the +1 for the second parameter?

Comment: @Thomas That's what I think the reason is for the segmentation fault...

Comment: By the way, using subtraction in your cmpfunc is not a good idea: what if `*a` is the smallest possible integer and `*b` is positive?

Comment: Well, have you tried it without the +1 ? What was your rationale for adding one in the first place?

Comment: @Thomas I tried without +1 but I didn't work. Becasue the Pos value start from 0.

Comment: @alan you don't seem to be understanding the point of that statement. You said yourself in your question, *"venueArray[i].Pos count the total element in the venueArray.number"*. Thusly, it makes no sense to add one. If it is the count, then *it is the count*. Unrelated, you said "in each `venueArray.number`, implying there is more than one. You checked the results of your `malloc` calls, *right* ?

Comment: To add to @WhozCraig's comment: is `venueArray[i].Pos` <= `1000000`?

Comment: Regardless. Post a *full* [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the problem. You already have the only best-guess speculation we can offer, and that's all it is: a guess.

Comment: @Thomas Thank you guys. I checked both **venueArray[i].Pos <= 1000000** and the** venueArray[i].Pos**. They are both fine. I would like to rewrite the **cmpfunc**

Comment: @alan Might it rather be that Pos does *not* hold the size of the array number (which is constantly 1 000 000 then - by the way use a constant then instead of magic numbers), so does not *count the total elements*, as you wrote, but is an index to somwhere within the array?